# EF Code First Many to Many relationship - Inserting duplicate records to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a third party service from which I'm getting a large collection of data and I want to store that information in my local database. Suppose I have 3 tables in my database **User**, **Role** and **UserRole**.

1. User table contains the following fields - UserId(PK), UserName.
2. Role table contains the following fields - RoleId(PK), RoleName.
3. UserRole table contains the following fields - UserId(FK),RoleId(FK).

So there is a **Many To Many** relationship between User and Role table.

When I try to save the following records to database its generating duplicate records in **Role** table.

```
using (CFAContext context = new CFAContext())
{
    context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 1", Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { RoleName = "Role 1" }, new Role { RoleName = "Role 2" }, new Role { RoleName = "Role 3" } } });
    context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 2", Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { RoleName = "Role 1" }, new Role { RoleName = "Role 2" } } });
    context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 3", Roles = new List<Role> { new Role { RoleName = "Role 1" }, new Role { RoleName = "Role 4" } } });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can I insert this list to database(User and Role) without any duplicate records in **User** and **Role** table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the `RoleId` fields are unique identifiers, thus for each role you have added, you will get a new record in the database with different `RoleId` fields as you are creating a new `Role` instance.

If you change your code to the following it will work;

```
Role role1 = new Role { RoleName = "Role 1" }
Role role2 = new Role { RoleName = "Role 2" }
Role role3 = new Role { RoleName = "Role 3" }
Role role4 = new Role { RoleName = "Role 4" }

context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 1", Roles = new List<Role> { role1, role2, role3 } });
    context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 2", Roles = new List<Role> { role1,role2 } });
    context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 3", Roles = new List<Role> { role1, role4 } });
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks daryal.My scenario is like I need to insert around 50000 rows, and the current list is in the format that I gave you in the question. So as per your suggestion, first of all I have to collect the list of Roles from the collection and while adding records to context I have to refer the above list of roles.Right? Is this is the right method for me or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Dennis you are right, first create roles, then use these roles while creating users, then persist.

Answer (score 0):

You are newing up 3 roles with the name "Role 1", I would create this record in the roles table and simply retrieve it when you need to assign it to a user.

Answer (score 0):

Below code creates 4 new Roles. If it is executed twice there will be 8 roles in db. If you don't want roles to be duplicated in other executions you should select them from context.

```
using (CFAContext context = new CFAContext())
{
    var roles = new List<Role> {
      new Role { RoleName = "Role 1" },
      new Role { RoleName = "Role 2" },
      new Role { RoleName = "Role 3" },
      new Role { RoleName = "Role 4" }
    };

    context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 1", Roles = new List<Role> { roles[0], roles[1], roles[2] } });
    context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 1", Roles = new List<Role> { roles[0], roles[1] } });
    context.Users.Add(new User { UserName = "User 1", Roles = new List<Role> { roles[0], roles[3] } });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

BTW how are your RoleId?

Comment: Thanks Mehmet. My scenario is like, I need to insert around 50000 rows, and the User and Roles table contains more than 10 columns.Since the relation is Many to Many the collection I'm getting from service conatins duplicate User and Role records. So as per your suggestion, first of all I have to collect the list of Roles and Users from the collection and while adding records to context I have to refer the above list of roles and users.Right? Is this is the right method for me or do you have any other suggestions?